# Distance between objects with different attributes meaningful?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, distance

Let's say you have two sets of `apples` and you assign some attributes to them like `color`, `size` and `price`.
Then you have another set of..  `songs`, which you assign some attributes, too: `genre`, `length` and `loudness`.
All those objects can now be put in a multivariate space where you can calculate distances among all pairs of {apples, songs}. Is that meaningful somehow?

When I consider a set of apples and a set of `eggs`, it should be reasonable as both provide `colors`, `sizes` and `prices`.
But a set of `apples` and `songs`? On the other hand, both sets will populate the space somehow where you can calculate the distances. But when I notice apple5 is nearer to `song9` than `apple11`. Does this mean something?

Comment: What similarity do you hope to find between apples and songs? It is unclear to me what the goal is. Also, unless apples have genres and songs have colours, how did you calculate a space that both have coordinates on?

Comment: I have no goal, it's just a question that was popping up on my mind :) 
About the space, I thought that the space would be build up by all attributes (color, size, price, genre, length and loudness). And all the apples and songs will occupy certain coordinates, hence, distances should also be accessible though I'm not sure if they represent something useful?
While I think about it..  the apples will have attributes genre, length and loudness = 0. And the songs vice versa, so they will populate different regions in that multivariate space. So that won't be senseful..?!

Comment: The real value of those variables should be `NA`. Zero imputation can be misleading here. What you will observe is that apples resemble short, quiet songs. And that songs will resemble small, cheap apples. But this is purely artificial. If you impute e.g. the mean, you would conclude something completely different. Playing around with methods is fine to further your understanding, but I doubt anything meaningful can come from this comparison.

Comment: To conclude, it makes no sense to calculate distances between objects that do not share the same attributes(?).

Comment: Yeah not really. It's like apples to oranges (though I suppose those share more attributes than apples and songs).